# Excluding modules from Python package

Tags: python

I have the following directory structure:

```
package
├── __init__.py
└── core.py
```

where the contents of `core.py` are:

```
def my_super_cool_func():
    crufty_helper_func()
    pass

def crufty_helper_func():
    pass
```

and the contents of `__init__.py` are:

```
from .core import my_super_cool_func
```

Now, if I go into the Python REPL, I can `import package`. Moreover, I can do `package.my_super_cool_func()` and I can't do `package.crufty_helper_func()` (as expected). But what I can also do is `package.core.crufty_helper_func()`, which to me, is undesirable.

Is there any way of excluding modules in a Python package? Ideally, in the setup above, I'd prefer for the `core` module not to be visible in the `package` package.

Answer (score 0):

do use `__all__`in `__init__.py` as

`__all__ = ['my_super_cool_func']`

then you can use it as `from package import my_super_cool_func` or

```
import package

x= package.my_super_cool_func
```

learn  [`__all__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python)

Comment: So I've introduced the line `__all__ = ['my_super_cool_func']` into `__init__.py`, but `core` is still a visibile module in `package`?

Comment: well core is python package and you can access it, i don't know how can we make it unaccesible, try rename it to private module as `_core.py`

Comment: You can't *actually* make anything private in Python, you can just suggest (by convention) that it's not intended to be used/imported.

Comment: @CrazyChucky yes, there is no concept for private or public in python it is just conventional to use _ for private , as OP require  `core` cant be hide and can be accessible, but i suggest this to use in sense that others deveolopers got to know that  not to import this module directly

Comment: I was agreeing with you, and clarifying for OP. My apologies, that wasn't very clear.

Comment: @CrazyChucky don't be sorry, I also didn't explain enough earlier.

Comment: So having read more about `__all__`, does it not only apply when using `from package import *`?

Comment: @steeps when you use `from package import *` it will import all defined fucntions, class, variable in the file, but if you define `__all__` in the python file then it will import all function/class/variable which are define in the `__all__` only